# ngx translate - quotes in language json-file

Tags: json, angular, ngx-translate

How could I implement a text in a language-specific json-file which contains double quotes? json-specific escaping by backslash doesn't work, because ngx translate integrates the text "as it is" (including the backslash and the quotation sign) in the website.

Comment: You can use &quot; for double quotes sign in HTML

Comment: *json-specific escaping by backslash doesn't work, because ngx translate integrates the text "as it is*: I really doubt ngx-translate uses its own non-compliant json parser. It probably just uses the standard JSON.parse(), which will thus deal with escapes just fine. Do you have a complete minimal example reproducing the problem? As I expected, I can't reproduce it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-byexhk?file=src%2Fassets%2Fi18n%2Fen.json

Comment: I would like to have 2-colors-text in the json language file. For example: „my name is <span style =„color: blue“>JJJ</span>.“ This doesn‘t work and the reason is the quote in the quote - so to say. json-escaping seems not to be a proper solution for this issue.